# Is there a way to check whether an apk is the same apk that was used to install an existing app?

Tags: android, apk

I'm writing a deployment manager for a development group that does tons of app deployments to different devices. The user connects an Android device, then gives the deployment manager an apk and tells it to deploy and run on a device. Right now I'm blindly uninstalling the app if it already exists on the device, then installing it from apk, then launching it.

For load time's sake, I'd like to skip the uninstall and install steps if the installed version of the app matches the contents of the user-provided apk. (The local copy of the deployment manager may have never seen this device before, so it can't rely on a local record of previous deployments to tell whether the installed version of the app matches.)

I can't trust the apk version number, since another programmer might have used the same version number to deploy a local build to this device already. Likewise, we're all using the same key to sign the apks, so the signature isn't helpful.

Is there something like a hash of an apk that I can get and compare it to the hash of an installed app?

Comment: Have you checked this answer? https://security.stackexchange.com/a/220562; Also, what about running `sha256sum each.apk` and compare those values? You should consider using different signing keys for debug/release builds by the way.